# Vue.js - update child component's function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component with a prop, but also there's is a mounted function to init date and hour. How to update this function when data from parent is reloaded?

Parent component:

```
 <template>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item in occurrences">
            {{ item.title }} {{ item.completed }}</small>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <sourceupd class="source" v-bind:source='source'></sourceupd>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import axios from 'axios'
      import sourceupd from './SourceAndUpdated'

      export default {

        name: 'Occurrences',

        components: {
          sourceupd
        },

        data: function () {
          return {
            occurrences: [],
            source: 'ANPC'
          }
        },

        mounted: function () {
          var _self = this

          function callAPI () {
            // call api code
          }

          callAPI()

          setInterval(() => {
            callAPI()
          }, 1024 * 3)
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Child Component:

```
<template lang="html">
    <small class="source-ref">Fonte: {{ source }} | Actualização:{{ updated.hour }}:{{ updated.minutes }}</small>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      updated: {
        hour: '',
        minutes: ''
      }
    }
  },

  props: ['source'],

  mounted: function () {
    moment.locale('pt')

    this.updated.hour = moment().format('HH')
    this.updated.minutes = moment().format('mm')
    this.updated.seconds = moment().format('ss')
  }
}
</script>
```

When callAPI() is reloaded, I would like to update time as well. I'm newbie with Vue.js (or this kind of framework) and I'm struggling how to handle this kind of dynamic information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe use [`updated`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) instead of `mounted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

If the `source` property of your parent component is updated by `callAPI` then this would be as simple as moving your code into the `updated` handler.

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      updated: {
        hour: '',
        minutes: ''
      }
    }
  },

  props: ['source'],
  methods: {
    update(){
      moment.locale('pt')

      this.updated.hour = moment().format('HH')
      this.updated.minutes = moment().format('mm')
      this.updated.seconds = moment().format('ss')

    }    
  },
  updated: function () {
    this.update()
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.update()
  }
}
```

Since it's not clear that you are updating any properties of the `sourceupd`, another way would be to just call the method using a `ref`.

In the Parent component template:

```
<sourceupd ref="sourceupd" class="source" v-bind:source='source'></sourceupd>
```

In your mounted handler:

```
setInterval(() => {
  callAPI()
  this.$refs.sourceupd.update()
}, 1024 * 3)
```

And change `sourceupd`:

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      updated: {
        hour: '',
        minutes: ''
      }
    }
  },

  props: ['source'],

  methods: {
    update(){
      moment.locale('pt')

      this.updated.hour = moment().format('HH')
      this.updated.minutes = moment().format('mm')
      this.updated.seconds = moment().format('ss')

    }    
  },

  mounted: function () {
    this.update()
  }  
}
```

I should also point out that you should add `seconds` to the `updated` property of your data, otherwise it will not be reactive.

```
  updated: {
    hour: '',
    minutes: '',
    seconds: ''
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it works, only needed to change 'ref' by 'refs': this.$ref.sourceupd.update() => this.$refs.sourceupd.update()

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally pass `updated` as property to the child. That way, whenever the parent updates, so will the child.

I also wouldn't have it as an object, but a timestamp instead so you can do whatever you want with it more easily.

Also, I'd use filters for formatting the hours minutes and seconds.

My `Child` component would look something like:

```
const Child = {
  props: {
    updated: Number,
  },

  filters: {
    format (timestamp, format) {
      return moment(timestamp).format(format || 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
    },
  },

  template: `
    <div class="child">{{ updated | format('ss') }}</div>
  `,
}
```

Then, as you update the parent's `updated` property it'll flow down into the child component.